# Why I can't read any character in this Python code

Tags: python, file, io

I know, `w+` means both `read` and `write`, then I write this code to read some message from a txt file and write some message into it

This is my code:

```
f = open('test', 'w+')
f.write('yes yes yes\n')
print f.read()
......
f.close()
```

when i run it, It only print newline, and didn't print `yes yes yes`

then I open `test` file, I found `yes yes yes`was in it!

Why it' just print new line, but print `yes`, and what's the difference between `w+` & `r+`

Answer (score 11):

You should put cursor at the beginning of file before reading.

```
f.seek(0)
f.read()
```

Comment: according to the argument mode, w+ insures that the cursor is at the start of the file

Comment: There is only one cursor, it move when you read or write.  The writes move the cursor to the end of file.  To read you need to move it back to the beginning.

Comment: Considering the file is 0 length when opened with "w+", it couldn't possibly not be at the start of the file when you open it.

Comment: @Wooble True, but right after opening, @thlgood performs a write, and the only cursor, as @koblas says, will now point to the end of a non-empty file, hence the need for `f.seek(0)` before the read.

Answer (score 2):

To answer part 2 of the question

``r''   Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

``r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
         The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

``w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.